# JSP - how to pass a javascript var in session.setAttribute?

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, session

New to learning JSP, and trying out passing data between two pages.

I'm wondering if it is possible to pass a javascript variable to `session.setAttribute()`

At the moment, I can pass a string of text through 2 jsp files like so:

JSP1:

```
<% String text = "hello";
session.setAttribute("test", text);%>
```

JSP2:

```
var someText = "<%=session.getAttribute("test")%>"
```

which works fine.

However, is it possible to pass through a `var` into `session.setAttribute` instead? I store some data in a javascript variable and would like to send it across to the second JSP file.

So for example:

```
var number = 7;
<%session.setAttribute("test", number);%>
```

I've tried this out and I get the error "number cannot be resolved to a variable"

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried like this <%session.setAttribute("test", <%=number%>);%> ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You cannot do that since javascript executes on client & JSP executes on server side.

If you want to set javascript variable to JSP session, then you pass this variable through the URL like this

```
var number = 7;
window.location="http://example.com/index.jsp?param="+number;
```

Now receive this var in your JSP page like this

```
String var = request.getParameter("param");
```

Now set it in session

```
session.setAttribute("test", var);
```

EDIT :

```
var number = 7;
<%session.setAttribute("test", number);%>
```

In the above code, server will only execute the code inside <% %>. It does not know anything outside of the JSP tags. So, it will also dont know about your javascript variable `number`.

Server executes the code & the result will be sent to the browser, then your browser will execute that javascript code `var number=7;`.

Hope, now it is clear for you.

Comment: Brilliant, must remember to drill down in my head between client and server side! Will accept your answer when SO lets me in 4 mins :)

Comment: @Tom, Edited the answer for your better understanding. Hope it will help you.

Comment: @Harshit Hi with the code above, I am getting number cannot be resolved to a variable error message